# C program for BMI

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float h,w,BMI;

    printf("Enter height(m): ");
    scanf("%f",&h);
    printf("Enter weight(kg): ");
    scanf("%f",&w);

    BMI=w/(h*h);
    printf("BMI is: %f\n",BMI);

    if (BMI<=15.0)
        printf("Starvation\n");
    else if (BMI>=15.1&&BMI<=17.5)
        printf("Anorexic\n");
    else if (BMI>=17.6&&BMI<=18.5)
        printf("Underweight\n");
    else if (BMI>=18.6&&BMI<=24.9)
        printf("Ideal\n");
    else if (BMI>=25.0&&BMI<=25.9)
        printf("Overweight\n");
    else if (BMI>=30.0&&BMI<=30.9)
        printf("Obese\n");
    else if (BMI>=40.0)
        printf("Morbidly obese\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**On some inputs program is not giving the BMI status. what is wrong here?**

Comment: _On some inputs_  You don't want to tell us which ones?  You want us to guess?

Comment: Please try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Especially, read all the `if` conditions out loud.

Comment: your conditions are wrong. Think about where 17.55, 18.56, 25.99... are put

Comment: so for example 17.51?  you cant do floating point comparisons like this.  If you only want one decimal digit then multiply by 10 put in an (unsigned) integer and then do if 151 to 175 type of a thing.  even if you think you are clipping to a base 10 decimal point, you are not really.

Comment: for eg. (h=1.6,w=64),(h=1.6,w=45),(h=1.6,w=75),(h=1.6,w=85) and many other combinations

Answer (score 4):

There are gaps in your range checks. For example, BMI values between 15.0 and 15.1 are not accounted for. You can change the `if`, `else if`, ... chain so that all values are accounted for:

```
    if (BMI<=15.0)
        printf("Starvation\n");
    else if (BMI<=17.5)
        printf("Anorexic\n");
    else if (BMI<=18.5)
        printf("Underweight\n");
    else if (BMI<=24.9)
        printf("Ideal\n");
    else if (BMI<=25.9)
        printf("Overweight\n");
    else if (BMI<=30.9)
        printf("Obese\n");
    else
        printf("Morbidly obese\n");
```

You might need to change the boundaries slightly, since it is not clear from your question whereabouts between 15.0 and 15.1 the boundary between "Starvation" and "Anorexic" should lie, for example.

Comment: Additionally, the program is scanning into `float` objects but comparing to `double` values. In common implementations, scanning “15.1” into `float` will produce 15.1000003814697265625, but the `double` `15.1` will be 15.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375.